# Unable to insert data using generate_series() in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to insert all dates for next 10 days using below query.

```
INSERT INTO sda.all_dates (checkin)
SELECT CURRENT_DATE +  generate_series(0, 10) AS checkin;
```

but unable to do, getting error

```
INFO:  Function "generate_series(integer,integer)" not supported.
ERROR:  Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
```

when i execute only SELECT part it give correct result

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE +  generate_series(0, 10) AS checkin;
```

Comment: Do you get an error?  If so, include it in your message.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added error.

Comment: @AshutoshSIngh: Please accept my answer below if it helped you to achieve what you were looking for. This way, it won't be lost in thread and would help others who have similar issues :)

Comment: Redshift is not versioned and thus the older version can not ever be used by anyone I can't see why this question should stay open with them now supporting generate_series. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute only `SELECT`, the query is executed on leader node since no table scan is required, that is why you get the correct result.

 But when you involve redshift tables (like `INSERT INTO`) the query with generate_series() is executed on compute node, which is not a supported function in redshift.
If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Redshift doesn't support what you're looking for.

Refer : **[Amazon Redshift Documentation for unsupported functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html)**

`generate_series()` is one of the many postgres functions not supported by Amazon Redshift

Answer (score 1):

Generators are not supported in Redshift, as pointed above.

You have 2 options:

1) a small hack like this:

```
with
series as (
    select 1 as n
    union select 2
    union select 3
)
select (current_date+interval '1 day'*n)::date
from series
```

2) create a dimensional table that stores every date of the calendar so you'll have something like this:

```
select date 
from dim.calendar 
where date between current_date and current_date+interval '10 day'
```

you can create such table by running `generate_series()` in Postgres, copying the result to CSV and loading that CSV to Redshift, it has to be done once. Besides dates, you can have different derivatives from date (first date of the week, month, quarter, etc.) depending on your goals.

UPD: Redshift supports generate_series() now

Answer (score 0):

To work around this limitation, I exported the output of the query that contains `generate_series()` to my localhost, uploaded it to redshift and inserted the data through a copy command. I tried using `unload()`, but that command also fails when you're using `generate_series()`.